# Chromecast won't load my receiver app. Request on stick is pending

Tags: google-cast

I have taken the cast-chrome-sender-helloworld sample app from https://github.com/googlecast/cast-chrome-sender-helloworld and inserted my APP ID. The APP ID is associated with a URL that points to `http://<server>/<path>/chromecast` and please notice the lack of ending "/" or ".html" which I did on purpose because it's basically a servlet that handles the receiver.

My sender app sends the request to the chromecast stick alright. Using the debugger in Chrome I can see that the request to launch a specific app associated with my APP ID is received and the stick tries to load the receiving app from the above mentioned URL. However, I see the HTTP GET request is executed but it's state is "pending" for a while before (I guess) it times out.

Could this failure to load the receiver app be due to the whitelisted URL is without ".html"?

** Edited on the 27th of September

I still see the Chromecast browser issuing the correct request URL but it "hangs" with the network status message "pending". No requests hits my apache server. If I use a laptop to issue the same request on the same wifi network, then I get the following correct answer (using CURL):

```
curl -vvv http://server.domain.com/path/device/chromecast
* About to connect() to server.domain.com port 80 (#0)
*   Trying 192.168.1.42...
* connected
* Connected to server.domain.com (192.168.1.42) port 80 (#0)
> GET /path/device/chromecast HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.24.0 (x86_64-apple-darwin12.0) libcurl/7.24.0 OpenSSL/0.9.8y zlib/1.2.5
> Host: server.domain.com
> Accept: */*
> 
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Date: Fri, 27 Sep 2013 06:46:23 GMT
< Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
< Content-Type: text/html;charset=ISO-8859-1
< Content-Length: 1850
< Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID=81A3A6184F014A7FBEC60C0B6375E8B0; Path=/client-portal/; HttpOnly
< 
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/cast/js/receiver/1.0/cast_receiver.js">
  </script>
  <script type="text/javascript">

    cast.receiver.logger.setLevelValue(0);

    // Initialize and start the media playing receiver
    var receiver = new cast.receiver.Receiver(
        'REPLACED_WITH_MY_APPID', 
        [cast.receiver.RemoteMedia.NAMESPACE],
        "",
        5);
    var remoteMedia = new cast.receiver.RemoteMedia();
    remoteMedia.addChannelFactory(
        receiver.createChannelFactory(cast.receiver.RemoteMedia.NAMESPACE));

    receiver.start();

    window.addEventListener('load', function() {
      var elem = document.getElementById('vid');
      remoteMedia.setMediaElement(elem);

      var checkStatus = function() {
        var status = document.getElementById('status');
        var st = remoteMedia.getStatus()['state'];

        if( st == 0 || remoteMedia.getStatus()['current_time'] == 0 ) {
            status.style.display = 'block';
        }
        else {
            if( st == 1 && remoteMedia.getStatus()['current_time'] > 0 ) {
                status.innerHTML = 'Paused...';
                status.style.display = 'block';
            }
            else {
                status.innerHTML = remoteMedia.getStatus()['current_time'];
                status.style.display = 'none';
                elem.style.display = 'block';
            }
        }
      }
      setInterval(checkStatus, 1000);
    });
  </script>
  <title>Media Player App</title>
</head>
  <body>
    <video id="vid"
           style="position:absolute;top:0;left:0;height:100%;width:100%"></video>
    <div id="status" style="display:none; font-size:300%; position:absolute;top:40%;left:40%;">
      <img src="/images/chrome_loading.gif" width="60%">
    </div>
  </body>
* Connection #0 to host server.domain.com left intact
</html>* Closing connection #0f
```

The debugger just shows the following before reloading the "brain freeze" screen:
[image: Screenshot where host names are changed]

Comment: ".html" isn't required, I have a similar setup that works. Have you tried if the receiver URL works when just opening it in a browser (because that's all the chromecast really does)?

Comment: On the same network I can open the same URL and get the content. It is however sent as text/plain instead of text/html but the request sent from the Chromecast accepts all. I will see if I can convince Apache that this should be text/html.

Comment: @tchristensen : Have made sure you've correctly configured the Chromecast using "Send this Chromecast's serial number when checking for updates."?

Comment: Just checked again. The device is sending the serial number. One way to validate this is to connect using the debugger. If you can it means that the device is whitelisted and ie. the serial is sent.

Comment: I still see the chromecast browser issueing the correct URL but it "hangs" with the network status message "pending". No requests hits my apache server. If I use a laptop to issue the same request on the same wifi network, then I get the following correct answer (see question)

Answer (score 2):

Turns out that the Chromecast stick does not use the local wifi routers DNS, but rely on an external one. My problem was that the host I was contacting had a different ip address on my local lan. (Thanks Google for the help with debugging this).

The documentation on https://developers.google.com/cast/whitelisting states that it is okay to whitelist NAT'ed addresses however, I don't see how this could work since the external DNS typically are unaware of that:

> Two (2) URLs for the location of your receiver app, typically one for QA and one for production, on your server. A Receiver is a HTML5 web page that hosts your content on the Chromecast devices. Good Receiver URL's usually look like https://website.com/rcvr/myreceiver.html or https://website.com/qarcvr/myreceiver.html (It is ok for your receiver to be on an internal (NAT'd) IP address, but not localhost. They are rarely a top level domain.

I solved this by using [pagekite.net](http://pagekite.net), which allows me to have a public address reachable by the external DNS and still access my local development machines web server.